# JDBC - Is it possible to SELECT data from one table and store it in a javax.swing.JTable or a String[][]?

Tags: java, sql, swing, jdbc, mariadb

I've a table with several columns. But instead of looping over the `ResultSet`, and inserting every entry manually, is it possible to store data automatically in an `Array`/`ArrayList` so that it will be easy for me to show it to the user in a `JTable`?

Comment: By using a library that does it for you, yes. Then you'll have to learn to use that library though, so it won't be any easier in the end than just writing a method to store the results in an `ArrayList` yourself.

Comment: The easier approach is to load the data into a Vector since the DefaultTableModel will accept a Vector, not an ArrayList. If you want to use an ArrayList then you will need to create a custom TableModel.